# Blank display when I use link Routes in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

If I search `"http://localhost:3000/"` or `"http://localhost:3000/login"`, my display is completely blank.

app.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Login from './pages/login'
import Home from './pages/home'
import Error from './pages/error'
import { Link, Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<Error />} />
    </Routes>
  )
}
export default App;
```

home.js

```
import React from "react";

const Home = () => {
  return <h1>The Home</h1>;
};
  
export default Home;
```

Comment: remove this from routes 
<Route path="*" element={<Error />} />
and try

Comment: In the browser console are there any errors? What versions of `react` and `react-router-dom` are installed? You can check by running `npm list react react-router react-router-dom` in the terminal in the project's root directory. Where are you rendering any `Link` components? Can you [edit] the post to include all relevant code and details are part of a complete [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactor to look like:

```js
import { Route, Routes, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
// ...

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<Error />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```